# javascript variable to php array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I've made this code here and done some research and still have no idea how to insert javascript variable into php array. Is it possible, acctually?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var count = 1;
        var id = 1;
        $("#b").click(function(){
            for(i = <?php echo $row; ?>; i > 0; i--){
                $("#main").prepend('<div id="first'+count+'"></div>'); 
                count++;
            }
            count = 1;
            for(i = <?php echo $row; ?>; i > 0; i--){
                $('#first'+count+'').text('<?php echo $row['']; ?>'+count+'');
                count++;
                id++;
            }

        });
    });
    </script>
```

I wanted to put this "id" variable into **$row['']**.

Thanks for help.

Comment: This is not possible, try clicking "View Source" of your webpage.  PHP only exists on the server!

Comment: shiow a sample of the $row content and of the result you want in javascript

Comment: You cant do that. Goal of php notation is to generate web page on the server and return this result to the client. Javascript is emedded into this result and javascript execution is done by the browser (client side).

Comment: Ok, thank you i'll find another way

Answer (score 0):

store $row count value in hidden text and get the value onclick

Answer (score 0):

It depend by what exactly you want to do but you can do it in some way.

The Javascript code can do an XMLHttpRequest to the PHP page with an url like: /page.php?my_array_name[]=my_value_1&my_array_name[]=my_value_2

So in the php page you get an array inside $_GET['my_array_name'] with the variables passed by Javascript and you can send text back to use from the Javascript code.